# Css style not being applied on a specific case with EXPRESS and EJS

Tags: reactjs, express, ejs

I am using express with ejs as a templating language. I am facing an issue regarding the application of css properties which i have defined in a separate directory. i have defined multiple routes using app.get() function, however in a specific route my css porperties aren't being applied. I have no clue of what is actually going on. if i try to lookup in chrome's inspect tool. under the console section no errors or even warnings are present. and if i look under the network tab i can see the css file being transferred however after opening it, it seems to give me another strange html page.

I will be providing every single information about my issue regarding that specific route. Please find the related images below.

This is my folder structure that i am working in:
[folder structure. everything is under "new" directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hUiA.png)

Contents of app.js file:
[code for app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osi7W.png)

Contents of home.js file:
[code for home.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSrU5.png)

Contents of love.js file:
[code for love.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORNh0.png)

Contents of posts.js file:
[code for posts.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwN7s.png)

Contents of app.css file:
[Simple css properties being applied on body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU9qv.png)

after accessing route '/fallinlovewith/rusty' no css is getting applied. however on the other routes my css is working perfectly fine.

[no css being applied in the route - '/fallinlovewith/rusty'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLKWu.png)

inspecting the page we can see that the css file app.css has been used.But if i open it seperately i get this weird thing that i have no idea whats happening.
[double clicking on app.css under the network tab, i get back this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA72p.png)

By the way, i am following my instructor Colt Steele who has this course on udemy named as the web developer bootcamp. I have followed everything just the way he types. despite that, i am having this weird issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet must be prefixed by the slash '`/`' in order to reference the root of website...

I see in your code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />`

It should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" />`

If you don't prefix by slash, the url will be appended to the current url...

***ps**: next time, copy your code instead of linking some screenshot... It'll be more easier for readers...*